# Vim - check if buffer is open in multiple windows

Tags: vim, window, buffer

Is there a way to check if a single buffer is open in multiple windows?
For example if you open up a file and you use the `:vsp` command, you can split up the current file into 2 windows, both looking at the same buffer, basically one buffer in two windows.

Single buffer:

[image]

The same buffer on two windows:

[image]

Is there a way to detect if one buffer is open in multiple windows via vimscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `win_findbuf()` function which will take a buffer number and return a list of Window-IDs.

```
:echo win_findbuf(bufnr('%'))
```

For more help see:

```
:h win_findbuf(
:h winid
:h bufnr()
```